# Populate backend datastore with data using upload script

Tags: macos, google-app-engine, csv, google-cloud-datastore

I am following this tutorial an have a lot of trouble with it as many parts are not explained to beginners: https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial

I came to the part where we need to upload some data to datastore. They are using a `.csv` file to accomplish that.

This is part of the tutorial where I've stuck:

```
Create Upload Script

This is the script that actually uploads the simulated information into the backend datastore.

For information about the bulkloader.yaml and more, refer to the App Engine documentation in: Uploading and Downloading Data. Also, you can find the bulkloader.yaml file and the test data here MobileAssistant-Data.

Create a new directory and make it your current directory.
In your editor, create a script file and call it upload_data.sh.
Copy and paste the following code into the file.
#!/bin/sh
appcfg.py upload_data
--config_file bulkloader.yaml --url=http://localhost:8888/remote_api --filename $1 --kind=$2 -e
nobody@nowhere.com
The previous script accepts two arguments separated by a blank space:

./upload_data.sh<data.csv> <class entity name>

The first argument is the name of the csv file that contains the data you want to upload, The second is the name of the entity class to handle the data.

Close and save the file. Notice that the script at this time is intended to be used on local server. It must be modified when the backend application is deployed to the cloud. For example, e-mail “nobody@nowhere.com ” will be changed to an actual e-mail address of the App Engine administrator before deployment.
Places Simulated Data

The simulated data is contained in the file places.csv that you downloaded earlier from the MobileAssistant-Data directory in Mobile Shopping Assistant.

The file contains the following comma separated fields:

name: <place’s name>
placeId: <number that identifies the place>
location: <place’s latitude and longitude coordinates (two values separated by a comma) >
key: <unique key associated with the place>
address: <the place’s address >
Modify Web.xml

To upload data to the datastore, reference the “remote API servlet” and associate it with a URL. You’ll define these mappings in the Web.xml file of the MobileAssistant-Appengine application, as shown next. The web server uses this configuration to identify the servlet to handle a given request.

Note. Notice, you might need to restart Eclipse. if you skip th e Web.xml modification you will get Error 404 Not Found.

<servlet>
<display-name>Remote API Servlet</display-name>
<servlet-name>RemoteApiServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>RemoteApiServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/remote_api</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
Upload Places Simulated Data

To upload the test data to the data store, run the script that uploads the data from your script directory.

Before you upload your data, make sure to start MobileAssistant-AppEngine as a Web Application (in Debug mode) in Eclipse.

./upload_data.sh <places.csv> Place
At the password request, just press enter.
```

I don't understand that part with the script. I created a folder `age` on Desktop, placed inside their files `bulkloader.yaml` and `places.csv`. Inside that folder is that upload script.

After I run `./upload_data.sh <places.csv> Place`, in my terminal I receive the following error:

```
upload_data.sh: line 2: appcfg.py: command not found
upload_data.sh: line 3: --config_file: command not found
upload_data.sh: line 4: nobody@nowhere.com: command not found
```

What should I do to upload that data to Google App Engine datastore? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is appcfg.py in your path, if not then set the path explicitly in your script or add the path the appcfg.py to your PATH

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but I am really not sure what I need to do. Where should i put my script and how to find appcfg.py? I don't see that file anywhere on my MAC.

Comment: appcfg.py will be found where ever you installed google_appengine SDK.

Comment: I installed Eclipse GAE plugin and now I see I have `appcfg.sh` there, not `appcfg.py`. I copied it to my folder but now I receive a message appcfg.sh cannot be found.

Comment: You can't do that, unless you are specific about paths.  You really need to spend some time working out how executable permissions are set, how path searching works on the command line, and how to actually find things. I don't use eclipse or OS/X so I have no idea where you have stuff installed.  But this is also very basic unix/linux skills and I would get my head around what is going on at this level if I where you.